# How can I override or reset the default location for Internet Explorer when File Uploading?

Tags: internet-explorer

When clicking the "Browse" button to upload a file from internet explorer it seems to be remembering the last location you read a file from. Is there anyway of overriding this value, or resetting it? I am not certain but it seems as though this may be a registry setting?

Comment: Do you want to reset it on the client or from the server?  Your server cannot do this - as the server knows nothing about the filesystem, it doesn't even know whether you're using windows or not.  From the client, yes, it has to be stored in the registry.  My suggestion would be to try uploading a file from some really funny directory - and then search for this directory in the registry.

Comment: Actually i can do it manually on the clients machine if need be as the client was pointing his machine at a drive that no longer exists. So everytime he now clicks the browse button the whole machine hangs. I will search for the registry for the address he mentioned and see if i can find the key.

Comment: Thanks Aleks i managed to find the entries in the registry. Location is as follows for any that are interested : My Computer\HKEY_USERS\123123123\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this, in the end thanks to @Aleks-g I was able to find the setting in the registry and update it that way.

The location in my case was:

My Computer\HKEY_USERS\123123123\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Cur‌​rentVersion\Explorer‌​\ComDlg3

Answer (score 0):

To enable this setting for multiple users, I used a Group Policy registry wizard that imports the keys under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg3` at startup.

Especially the subkeys `CIDSizeMRU` and `LastVisitedPidlMRU` and their subkeys and values are needed to set the default path for Internet Explorer when uploading files:

[image]